# angular not fetching data on jsfiddle

Tags: html, angularjs, jsfiddle

Why below code doesn't fetch data from js into html file?

https://jsfiddle.net/SaifHarbia/g64jxt4u/4/

HTML code

```
<head ng-app="myApp">
  <p1>
  mobile client
  </p1>
  <li> <p2>Mobile Client mangement</p2>
  <t>Edit Client</t></li>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mobilCtrl">
  <form >
    <table>
   <tr>
     <td>{{forms.fild1}}</td>
     <td></td>
     <td>{{forms.fild2}}</td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

  </body>
```

JS code

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('mobilCtrl', [ function($scope) { 


  $scope.forms = 
    [
        "fild1" : "customer name", 
        "fild2" :"national number" 
    ];


}]);
```

Comment: try changing `$scope.forms` to `{
        "fild1" : "customer name", 
        "fild2" :"national number" 
    };`

Answer (score 1):

I commented before really reading your code..
Why is there stuff inside your `<head>` tags?? Head is for meta, scripts, styles or title not for `<li>` elements etc!

Change your html to this:

```
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mobilCtrl">
    <p>mobile client</p>

    <p>Mobile Client mangement</p>Edit Client

    <form>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="mobile in forms">
                <td>{{mobile.fild1}}</td>

                <td></td>

                <td>{{mobile.fild2}}</td>

                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

your javascript should look like this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('mobilCtrl', function($scope) { 

  $scope.forms = [{

        "fild1" : "customer name", 
        "fild2" :"national number" 


  }];
});
```

Comment: I added that to my fiddle but still not working, it is hard to know where the problem is when you see everything well written, do you have the working code in a separate fiddle ?

Comment: the reason your fiddle isn't working is that the javascript is loaded at the wrong time. Go to the javascript settings and change it to `no wrap - in <body>` instead of onload.

Comment: i used to do that but it seems like the jsfiddle was updated and this feature was omitted, i dont know why they've done that

Comment: If you click on the cYou can change the load type there. Don't know when or why they changed it but yea can be tricky to find it the first time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the beginner's Angular JS tutorials to understand its structure. Because you are using the ng-app directive in head section.

Secondly, you can refer to this simple angular js fiddle to understand it.
[AngularJS Simple Example - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div>Hello {{ user.firstName }}</div>
    <input ng-model="user.firstName"></input>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login"></input>
    <div ng-repeat="login in logins">{{ login }}</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        firstName: "Foo",
        lastName: "Bar"
    };
    $scope.logins = [];
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.logins.push($scope.user.firstName + " was logged in.");
    };
}
```